# Incorrect result in SHACL validation

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, shacl

I am trying to validate a data graph against the shape graph using pyshacl. Basically, the data graph represents a geometric representation of two walls in a building, whose distance from each other is around 12.5 meters. The shapes graph checks if the distance between the walls is less than 10 meters. The code I am using is as follows:

```
from pyshacl import validate
from rdflib import Graph
Datagraph = '''
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix bot: <https://w3id.org/bot#> .
@prefix ifc: <https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC2x3/TC1/OWL#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix lbd: <https://linkebuildingdata.org/LBD#> .
@prefix props: <http://lbd.arch.rwth-aachen.de/props#> .
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/> .
@prefix IFC4-PSD: <https://www.linkedbuildingdata.net/IFC4-PSD#> .
@prefix smls: <https://w3id.org/def/smls-owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix inst: <https://www.ugent.be/myAwesomeFirstBIMProject#> .
@prefix fog: <https://w3id.org/fog#> .

inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353
        props:objectTypeIfcObject  inst:objectTypeIfcObject_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:reference            inst:reference_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:extendToStructure    inst:extendToStructure_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:loadBearing          inst:loadBearing_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:isExternal           inst:isExternal_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:category             inst:category_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        rdf:type                   bot:Element ;
        props:globalIdIfcRoot      inst:globalIdIfcRoot_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:nameIfcRoot          inst:nameIfcRoot_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        props:batid                inst:batid_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 ;
        geo:hasGeometry            inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry .

inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry
        fog:asObj_v3.0-obj  "diAzODcyLjM3ODM0NTUyNjY4OSAtNDY2LjM1NTc3MjU3ODAzNjA3IDAuMAp2IDM4NzIuMzc4MzQ1NTI2Njg5IC00NjYuMzU1NzcyNTc4MDM2MDcgNzk5OS45OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkKdiAzODcyLjM3ODM0NTUyNjY4OSAtNDA2Ni4zNTU3NzI1NzgwMzY1IDAuMAp2IDM4NzIuMzc4MzQ1NTI2Njg5IC00MDY2LjM1NTc3MjU3ODAzNjUgNzk5OS45OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkKdiA0MTYyLjM3ODM0NTUyNjY4OSAtNDY2LjM1NTc3MjU3ODAzNjA3IDAuMAp2IDQxNjIuMzc4MzQ1NTI2Njg5IC00NjYuMzU1NzcyNTc4MDM2MDcgNzk5OS45OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkKdiAzODcyLjM3ODM0NTUyNjY4OSAtN"^^<https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary> ;
        lbd:hasBoundingBox  inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry_bb .
        
inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry_bb
        lbd:z-max  "7999.999999999999"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:z-min  "0.0"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:y-max  "-466.35577257803607"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:y-min  "-4066.3557725780365"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:x-max  "4162.378345526689"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:x-min  "3872.378345526689"^^xsd:double .
        
inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd
        props:nameIfcRoot          inst:nameIfcRoot_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:reference            inst:reference_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:loadBearing          inst:loadBearing_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:objectTypeIfcObject  inst:objectTypeIfcObject_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:globalIdIfcRoot      inst:globalIdIfcRoot_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:category             inst:category_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:isExternal           inst:isExternal_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        geo:hasGeometry            inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry ;
        lbd:containsInBoundingBox  inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c31b ;
        props:batid                inst:batid_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        props:extendToStructure    inst:extendToStructure_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd ;
        rdf:type                   bot:Element .

inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry
        fog:asObj_v3.0-obj  "diAtODYzNy42MjE2NTQ0NzMyOTIgLTQzNTYuMzU1NzcyNTc3OTk2IDAuMAp2IC04NjM3LjYyMTY1NDQ3MzI5MiAtNDM1Ni4zNTU3NzI1Nzc5OTYgNzk5OS45OTk5OTk5OTk5OTkKdiAtODYzNy42MjE2NTQ0NzMyOTIgODI0My42NDQyMjc0MjIwMSAwLjAKdiAtODYzNy42MjE2NTQ0NzMyOTIgODI0My42NDQyMjc0MjIwMSA3OTk5Ljk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OQp2IC04OTI3LjYyMTY1NDQ3MzI5MiAtNDM1Ni4zNTU3NzI1Nzc5OTYgMC4wCnYgLTg5MjcuNjIxNjU0NDczMjkyIC00MzU2LjM1MCAxMTcgMTE4CmYgMTIyIDEyNCAxMjMKZiAxMjIgMTIxIDEyNApmIDEyNyAxMjggMTI1CmYgMTI4IDEyNiAxMjUKZiAxMjkgMTMwIDEzMQpmIDEzMiAxMjkgMTMxCg=="^^<https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary> ;
        lbd:hasBoundingBox  inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry_bb .

inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry_bb
        lbd:z-max  "7999.999999999999"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:z-min  "0.0"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:y-max  "8243.64422742201"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:y-min  "-4356.355772577996"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:x-max  "-8637.621654473292"^^xsd:double ;
        lbd:x-min  "-8927.621654473292"^^xsd:double .
'''
Shapegraph = ''' 
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix bot: <https://w3id.org/bot#> .
@prefix ifc: <https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC2x3/TC1/OWL#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix lbd: <https://linkebuildingdata.org/LBD#> .
@prefix props: <http://lbd.arch.rwth-aachen.de/props#> .
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/> .
@prefix IFC4-PSD: <https://www.linkedbuildingdata.net/IFC4-PSD#> .
@prefix smls: <https://w3id.org/def/smls-owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix inst: <https://www.ugent.be/myAwesomeFirstBIMProject#> .
@prefix fog: <https://w3id.org/fog#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

ifc:geometricconstraintshape a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:targetClass bot:Element;
        sh:sparql[
            sh:message "The geometric constraint is violated" ;
            sh:select """
            SELECT $this
            WHERE{
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 geo:hasGeometry $this .
                $this lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall1bb.
                ?wall1bb lbd:x-min ?x_min.
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd geo:hasGeometry $this .
                $this lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall2bb.
                ?wall2bb lbd:x-max ?x_max.
                FILTER (ifc:computedistance(?x_min,?x_max)<=10.0) .
                } """ ;
            ] .
        
ifc:computedistance a sh:SPARQLFunction;
    rdfs:comment "Finds the distance between the two elements";
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path lbd:x_min ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The inner x coordinate of the wall on the right side";
        ];
    
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path lbd:x_max ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The outer x coordinate of the wall on the left side";
        ];
    
    sh:returnType xsd:double;
    sh:select"""
    SELECT (BIND(($x_min - $x_max)/1000) AS ?result)
    WHERE {
        }
    """.
'''

r = validate(data_graph = Datagraph, shacl_graph = Shapegraph, data_graph_format="ttl", shacl_graph_format="ttl", inference = "rdfs", debug = True, abort_on_error = False, meta_shacl = False, serialize_report_graph = "ttl")
conforms, results_graph, results_text = r
```

Since the actual distance between the walls is around 12510mm (I have divided the calculated distance by 1000 in the shape to convert it into meters), the datagraph should not confirm to the shape graph. However, in my case, the result I am getting is "Datagraph conforms to constraints".

Not sure where I am making a mistake in developing the shape. Could anyone please help to identify the mistake and suggest how to correct it? Thanks in advance.

I also tried a simpler query to avoid function call as follows:

```
ifc:geometricconstraintshape a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:targetClass bot:Element;
        sh:sparql[
            sh:message "The geometric constraint is violated" ;
            sh:select """
            SELECT $this
            WHERE{
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 geo:hasGeometry $this .
                $this lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall1bb.
                ?wall1bb lbd:x-min ?x_min.
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd geo:hasGeometry $this .
                $this lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall2bb.
                ?wall2bb lbd:x-max ?x_max.
                BIND ((?x_min - ?x_max)/1000 AS ?result) .
                FILTER (?result<=10.0) .
                } """ ;
            ] .
```

Still, I am not getting the correct results.

To avoid any issue due to incorrect target nodes, I wrote the query in another form as shown below:

```
ifc:computedistance a sh:SPARQLFunction;
    rdfs:comment "Finds the distance between the two elements";
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path ifc:op1 ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The inner x coordinate of the wall on the right side";
        ];
    
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path ifc:op2 ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The outer x coordinate of the wall on the left side";
        ];
    
    sh:returnType xsd:double;
    sh:select"""
    SELECT ?result
    WHERE {
        BIND ((($op1 - $op2)/1000) AS ?result).
        }
    """.
    
ifc:lessThan a sh:SPARQLFunction;
    rdfs:comment "Returns if op1<op2.";
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path ifc:op1;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The difference between the two coordinates";
        ] ;
    
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path ifc:op2;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The constraint value to be checked against";
        ] ;
    
    sh:returnType xsd:boolean ;
    sh:select """
        SELECT ?result
        WHERE {
            BIND (IF(?op1<?op2, true, false) AS ?result).
            }
        """.

ifc:geometricconstraintshape a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:targetClass bot:Element;
        sh:expression[
            sh:message "The geometric constraint is violated" ;
            ifc:lessThan(
                [
                    ifc:computedistance(
                        [sh:path (inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry_bb lbd:x-min)]
                        [sh:path (inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry_bb lbd:x-max)]
                        )
                    ]
                10.0
                );
            ].
        
'''
```

However, still, the datagraph is confirming to all values of constraint in the shape graph.

Comment: check your SPARQL query. You use the same variable `?x_min` for both wall instances. That's obviously an empty resultset, thus, no violation. It should be `?wall2bb lbd:x-max ?x_max.`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @UninformedUser. Yes, I changed it to x_max, still getting the same result.

Comment: sure - your query is still a bit weird to me, but I don't know the purpose if it to be honest. For example, I don't get why you hard-code two walls instances. Anyways, your query also uses `$this` as variable, and this clearly can't be shared among both walls as each wall has a different geometry entity. You have to use different variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @UninformedUser. Just to clarify, the purpose of the query is to validate the distance between two walls. I had to hard-code as I could not find a way to make them target nodes, without knowing what exactly they are (there are other elements as well in the datagraph, which I have not entered here). As suggested, I added another variable $that for the second wall, still I am seeing that the datagraph confirms to the shape for all values in FILTER.

Comment: To avoid any issue due to incorrect target nodes, I have written the query in another form. However, still, the datagraph is confirming to the shape graph for all values of the constraint. I am wondering is it really because of the problem in shape or some issue in the datagraph?

Comment: isn't the idea of a SPARQL query constraint to return all solutions that violate your constraint? So you have to change your FILTER to get all solutions with a distance larger than 10.0 or not?

Comment: works for me with `PREFIX inst: <https://www.ugent.be/myAwesomeFirstBIMProject#>
            prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
            prefix lbd: <https://linkebuildingdata.org/LBD#>

            SELECT $this1
WHERE{
inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 geo:hasGeometry $this1 .
$this1 lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall1bb.
 ?wall1bb lbd:x-min ?x_min.
 inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd geo:hasGeometry $this2 .
$this2 lbd:hasBoundingBox ?wall2bb.
?wall2bb lbd:x-max ?x_max.
BIND ((?x_min - ?x_max)/1000 AS ?result) .
FILTER (?result > 10.0) .
}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried pasting the same code in my SHACL shape, but it is still not working for me.  I am still getting 'Datagraph coforms to constraint' for all values of constraint in the FILTER. Not sure, but are you suggesting not to use a SHACL shape and use a SPARQL query instead to directly query the results from the data graph? However, my objective was to validate the data graph against a constraint, rather than finding out solutions of distance greater than 10.0.

Comment: no, I just used the query above for the SPARQL based NodeShape and it returns a violation. Where do you run it?

Comment: Where do you run it? I used Apache Jena CLI, you have to ensure that SPARQL based constraints are supported in your tool

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running it on pyshacl. Not sure if it supports the SPARQL-based constraints. Will try Apache Jena CLI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @UninformedUser. It worked on Apache Jena CLI.